# Phonegap Cordova best way to display PDF document

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I have site with ~100k pdf documents and I'd like to create phonegap android application.
I'm looking for best way to display PDF documents in application.

What is best way..tool or something, that allow me do that? 
Main focus is to get best UX as I can. It should be fast and easy to use.

Already I've tested PDF.js but maybe there's other, better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [**In App Browser**](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) plugin.

You can install it by running:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

in your CLI (*in case if you are using Cordova 3.x*).
Earlier versions such (2.8.0, 2.9.0 etc) should have it pre-installed.

Ton open PDF documents in a new window use:

```
window.open('http://your-url.com/yourPDF.pdf', '_blank');
```

You might be able to use `'_system` option instead of `'_blank'` but i'm not sure about the outcome, it might open a system defined PDF viewer.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it like that: window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/pdf.pdf&embedded=true', '_system', 'location=no'); But it still something that not satisfied me.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer on the [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com) team*

You could have a look at https://github.com/PSPDFKit/Cordova-iOS and https://github.com/PSPDFKit/Cordova-Android. Both plugins are wrapping PSPDFKit and allow viewing PDF documents as simple as

```
function showMyDocument() {
    PSPDFKit.showDocument('file://.../document.pdf');
}
```

Comment: I doesn't have a user for the website... How can I create a user?

Comment: @CarlosGaleano you can request a demo version using this link: https://pspdfkit.com/#trynow

Comment: Trying...! Thank you!

Comment: This is not free. You need a license key. Also, it doesn't let you uninstall with cordova plugin remove pspdfkit-cordova-android. Can NOT recommend, removing manually is a major pain.

Comment: PSPDFKit is a commercial PDF framework. However, the Cordova plugins are open source and free. Removing using the `cordova` command should work. It might be that this is a bug. If this is the case, we would really appreciate if you could open an issue on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: @david.schreiber Hi ! , i also tried implementing the cordova-android plugin for pspdfkit, but unfortunately its not showing up the document for editing. I followed all the steps said in the github readme. Pls help me correct this problem. I have posted a question on this issue. The link is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631997/how-to-implement-the-cordova-android-plugin-for-pspdfkit

Comment: @MidhunKrishna We answered you on the other question.